# Chaosmonkey Go Package Install

Tags: go, netflix, spinnaker, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I have been trying to install `chaosmonkey` following the instruction from [here](https://www.gremlin.com/chaos-monkey/chaos-monkey-tutorial/#how-to-install-chaos-monkey) using `go`

However, I have not been able to successfully resolve the issue for the past day. I keep getting the below error and if I try installing other packages using `go get`, it install it without any issue so I believe my `path` is correct.

```
go: downloading github.com/netflix/chaosmonkey v2.0.2+incompatible
go get: module github.com/netflix/chaosmonkey@v2.0.2 found (v2.0.2+incompatible), but does not contain package github.com/netflix/chaosmonkey/cmd/chaosmonkey
```

There is not much information on the internet and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `go install github.com/netflix/chaosmonkey/cmd/chaosmonkey`. The README is wrong, `go get` is for libraries not commands.

Comment: That project has not been updated in a long time, and is not compatible with go modules. You either need to update the package to work with modules, or set `GO111MODULE=off`.

Comment: @JimB thanks! setting `GO111MODULE=off` worked!